# Spring Boot 3.1.2 Not able to identify one of the configuration class from another library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-3

I have the plain spring boot application and for logging that depends on the other maven library which is developed by me only. This setup was working for spring boot version 2.7 but now I want t o upgrade my application to Spring Boot 3.X.X. In this set up the configuration class which is there in the logging library is getting completely ignored. Below is my class and configurations.

```
package com.abc.xyz.sample;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleConsumerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleConsumerApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

My logging library have below configuration class.

```
package com.abc.xyz.logging

@Configuration
public class LoggingConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public LoggingBean getLogginBean() {
        return new LoggingBean();
    }
}
```

Configuration class is getting completely ignored. Can anyone help in this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Solution is Spring.factories is no more the correct way for Auto configuring. You need to add `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` inside META-INF/spring and put all your classes in it without comma or anything else.

for e.g. `com.abc.xyz.logging.LoggingConfiguration`

Spring doc for your reference [Spring 3 Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring Boot 2.7 there is a new mechanism for auto-configuration registration, see [the announcement](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#changes-to-auto-configuration). The old mechanism was declared as deprecated, but still supported.

Since Spring Boot 3.0 the old mechanism for auto-configuration is not supported anymore, see the [migration guide notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#auto-configuration-files).

Therefore you probably need to migrate your auto-configuration from the now unsupported `META-INF/spring.factories` files to `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` files.

Answer (score -1):

your  application starter path is `package com.abc.xyz.sample;`
and your configuration path is `package com.abc.xyz.logging`.

have you ever notice where is strange? yes, you define your  spring configuration without indicate  `SpringBootApplication` annotation base args `scanBasePackage`explicit , so spring could not found your configuration ,and there is two way  fix it , choose the one your prefer;

##### Solution

1. move ExampleConsumerApp in path `com.abc.xyz`
2. define `scanBasePackage={"com.abc.xyz",}`  in  `SpringBootApplication` annotation

Comment: Other library configurations such as com.abc.xyz.template is getting scanned and why not this logging ?

Comment: post the structure  . and you just mention other library in your project ,may be  there is potential auto-configuration in it ?  and try to define the  scanBasePackage path as root path

Comment: have added spring.factories with EnableAutoConfiguration in both the libraries. But one is getting auto configured and another one is not.